# Como fazer a transmissão de uma radio fm no meu site?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Um cliente quer um sistema para sua rádio onde será feita a transmissão do seu programa, parecido com [esse aqui](http://www.caracafm.com.br/). Nunca fiz nada nesse estilo e gostaria de saber como coloco esse player no site. Desenvolvo usando o Rails. Eu pesquisei mas não consegui encontrar nada, sempre aparece algo relacionado a radio buttons kkk. Se alguém puder me indicar um tutorial bacana agradeceria muito.

Obs: não sei qual tag usar nesse caso, usei `ruby-on-rails` por ser a ferramenta que vou utilizar mas acho que isso não interfere muito.

Comment: mas qual é a radio dele?

Comment: Se é am ou fm que você está perguntando? É fm

Comment: o endereço da radio dele, tipo algo parecido com `http://104.167.9.191:9326/;stream`

Comment: Eu não sei, sou completamente leigo nesse assunto. Esse é o endereço do site atual da rádio: http://www.radioalfa.com.br/. Dei uma inspecionada no código pelo browser mas não descobri nada. Pra fazer a transmissão de uma radio na web tem que usar algum serviço de hospedagem?

Comment: Coloca num iframe na sua pagina `<iframe src="http://www.radioalfa.com.br/topowz3.php" height="60" width="100%"></iframe>`

Comment: Mas no caso esse site vai deixar de existir, irei refazê-lo. Gostaria de saber como construir um player desse do 0. Peço desculpas pois imagino que minhas perguntas sejam bobas por eu não entender nada

Comment: Se o site deixar de existir a radio também vai deixar de existir não é?

Comment: Sim, isso que gostaria de entender melhor. Caso o site deixe de existir, como eu crio esse player em um novo site? Eu olho o código fonte e td gira em torno do domínio atual. Como devo proceder quando esse domínio deixar de existir? Preciso contratar um serviço de hospedagem pra transmitir uma rádio FM na web?

Comment: http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2013/10/como-criar-uma-radio-online-de-graca-com-sites-de-streaming.html

Comment: https://maxcast.com.br/criar-radio-online-gratis/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq9PzlteV3AIVQ1mGCh052QgkEAAYASAAEgKjp_D_BwE

Comment: no google tá cheio. Pesquise, como criar uma radio web